# Problem on Ages

Tags: number-theory

When her grandmother died Mindy was as old as her youngest sister is now. When her grandfather died Mindy was as old as her Younger brother will be 3 years from now. If the death of the grandfather and grandmother was 6 years apart, find the age difference between Mindy’s younger brother and Mindy’s younger sister.

Answer (score 0):

From the first statement, Mindy is $6$ years older than the younger sister. From the second statement, Mindy is $3$ years older than her younger brother. So their age difference is $3$ years.

Comment: Let grandmother died a years ago.
Younger sister's age now = x years.
Mindy's age now = (x+a) years.

Let grandfather died b years ago.
Younger brother's age now = y years.
Mindy's age now = (b+y+3) years.

Now, given |a-b|=6.

Equating Mindy's age, 
x+a=b+y+3 $\Rightarrow$ x-y=b-a+3=6+3=9
$\Rightarrow$ age difference between Mindy’s younger brother and Mindy’s younger sister = 9 years.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find the difference so “now” can be conveniently defined as we choose; define it as when grandfather dies.

$6$ years ago, mindy was as old as her sister so they will always be $6$ years difference.

Now, mindy is $3$ years older than the brother. Clearly then, $6-3=3$ years difference.

Comment: Let grandmother died a years ago.
Younger sister's age now = x years.
Mindy's age now = (x+a) years.

Let grandfather died b years ago.
Younger brother's age now = y years.
Mindy's age now = (b+y+3) years.

Now, given |a-b|=6.

Equating Mindy's age, 
x+a=b+y+3 $\Rightarrow$ x-y=b-a+3=6+3=9
$\Rightarrow$ age difference between Mindy’s younger brother and Mindy’s younger sister = 9 years.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that when Mindy's grandfather died, her age was $x$ years. So by given condition her younger sister's age at present is same i.e $x$.

Now, after $6$ years, when her grandmother died, Mindy's age is $x+6$ which is $3$ years older than her younger brother. So her younger brother's age presently is $x+3$.

Difference = $(x+3)-3 = 3 \text{ years
}$

Comment: Let grandmother died a years ago.
Younger sister's age now = x years.
Mindy's age now = (x+a) years.

Let grandfather died b years ago.
Younger brother's age now = y years.
Mindy's age now = (b+y+3) years.

Now, given |a-b|=6.

Equating Mindy's age, 
x+a=b+y+3 $\Rightarrow$ x-y=b-a+3=6+3=9
$\Rightarrow$ age difference between Mindy’s younger brother and Mindy’s younger sister = 9 years.

Answer (score 0):

Let grandmother died a years ago.
Younger sister's age now = x years.
Mindy's age now = (x+a) years.

Let grandfather died b years ago.
Younger brother's age now = y years.
Mindy's age now = (b+y+3) years.

Now, given |a-b|=6.

Equating Mindy's age, 
x+a=b+y+3 $\Rightarrow$ x-y=b-a+3=6+3=9
$\Rightarrow$ age difference between Mindy’s younger brother and Mindy’s younger sister = 9 years.